# Option not declared?

Tags: packages, options

I've managed to confuse myself into not being able to code up options for a style file that I want to use. Here's the MWE.

Main Latex File

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[author]{style-for-option}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The Style file referenced in the preamble:

```
\title{Title specified outside of option}

\DeclareOption{author}{\author{Author specified via ``Author'' Option}}
```

After I've saved the two files in the same directory, I get the error that the *author* option wasn't declared in the style file. The style file is definitely found by the compiler, because the title of the resulting document is correct: it reads "Title specified outside of option", exactly as desired.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you probably want to add `\ProcessOptions` to the .sty

Comment: Yup, that was my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add `\ProcessOptions` to the .sty